# How to map segmentation fault address to the corresponding C code?

Tags: c, linux

I see a segmentation fault like this `segfault at 157e8250 ip 157e8250 sp bfa3fdfb` how do I map the this address to the corresponding code where the fault occurs?

Answer (score 5):

Use the addr2line utility from the [GNU binutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) suite.  For example, this prints out the filename, line number, and function name (demangling it if it's a C++ function) for the faulting address 0x157e8250:

```
addr2line -e my_executable_file -C -f 0x157e8250
```

You can also pass on any number of addresses in the command line, e.g. if you have a stack trace of only instruction addresses.

Make sure you compile your program with the `-g` compiler option to generate debugging symbols, otherwise `addr2line` will not be able to symbolicate anything for you.

Answer (score 5):

1. you should add the "-g" option of gcc
2. use gnu tool "addr2line", like,

   ```
   # addr2line -e a.out 0x80484c8 -f

   -e: executable file name
   -f: generate function name
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the source code that you can compile. If you compile it with debugging symbols and run it in gdb, it will print you the stack trace with line numbers and other good stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using Valgrind.  The usage is:
`valgrind <your program name> <command-line arguments to your program>`.  If you compile with debug symbols on (use the `-g` option in gcc) you'll get the exact line number of every level in the stack where the segfault occurred.